# Read Data from Editable Text Field in WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, text, textfield, win32gui

I have to read data that is inserted into editable textfield in windows.

Just to test, I created following test code.

```
//Define variable and textfield
LPTSTR radiusValue;
HWND hwndradiusValue;

//Create Text Field. Note that, hWnd is handler to original window
hwndradiusValue=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 50, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

//Get Text from handle
GetWindowText(hwndradiusValue,radiusValue,30);
//Display the message
MessageBox(NULL, radiusValue, "TESTING", MB_OK);
```

I was expecting the Message to display the item in the textfield. But it did not. It displayed Null Charater. How can I solve this?

Comment: You created an edit control without content (`TEXT("")`). Also, you're mixing character encodings. If you are using the `TEXT` (or `_T`) macro, do so consistently. You should study [Working with Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407.aspx) in the MSDN. You also seem to have a pimped SDK installed; mine doesn't define the type `LTPSTR`. If that is supposed to be an `LPTSTR` instead, you're writing to random memory.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your comment.

Even if I do TEXT("SOMERADIUS"), it does not display SOMERADIUS.

I am using LPTSTR. That was a typo. What do you mean you are writing to random memory?

Comment: `GetWindowText` writes the contents to the address pointed to by `radiusValue`. This is an uninitialized pointer. You have to provide the storage yourself, i.e. `TCHAR radiusValue[30] = { 0 }; GetWindowText( hwndradiusValue, radiusValue, ARRAYSIZE( radiusValue ) );`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a character storage variable when you want to retrieve the text, not an uninitialised pointer variable!

```
TCHAR radiusValue[30];
GetWindowText(hwndradiusValue, radiusValue, _countof(radiusValue));
```

Comment: Or use `GetWindowTextLength()` and allocate the storage dynamically.